# postgres corrupted shared memory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04, postgresql-12

i am trying to use postgresql to process queries on GPU using PG_strom.
whenever i try to process queries i got issue:

```
postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current
transaction and exit, because another 
server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

i have checked that i have to increase shared buffer and work memory these are my current configuartions:

```
shared_buffers = 10GB
work_mem = 1GB
```

i want to know how can i increase them to its maximum limit as whenever i try to increase them i couldn't connect to postgresql.

Comment: "i have checked that i have to increase shared buffer and work memory"  You checked with whom or with what?

Comment: Look in the database server's log file.  It should give you more details on the original problem, and also on the new problem.

Comment: i found some people who say that this issue occurs because it exceed shared memory .

Comment: for log file:
LOG:  server process (PID 42261) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
 DETAIL:  Failed process was running: INSERT INTO "p166_td_node_22" SELECT * from "p166_td_node_22_v"
2020-12-13 19:02:01.133 CET [10733] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
logicsem@logicsem WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
logicsem@logicsem DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.